# PHP Multiple file upload to SQL, Only first file is uploaded

Tags: php, sql-server

I am uploading multiple files and trying to store their details in an SQL database, but only the first file is uploaded and stop uploading the rest of the selected files.

Here is my HTML to grab multiple files in a form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="my_file[]" type="file" id="userfile" multiple> 
   <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
</form>
```

My PHP code for uploading files info such as names and types:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){    
   if (($_FILES['my_file']['name']!="")){
      for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($_FILES['my_file']['name']) ; $i++){ 
         $target_dir = "upload_test/";
         $file = $_FILES['my_file']['name'][$i];
         $path = pathinfo($file);
         $ext = $path['extension'];
         $target_dir = $target_dir.basename($file);
         $user = "xxx";

         if(insertFile_info(basename($file) , $target_dir, $user, $ext, $conn)){
            echo "Insert file success";
         }else{
            echo "Insert Failed";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For example, if I choose `file1`,`file2` & `file3`. Only `file1`'s info is inserted to db, but the `file2` & `file3` did not insert to the database at all.

Whats the problem here?

Here is my insert method:

```
function insertFile_info ($file_name , $path, $username, $type, $conn){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO URL (file_name, path, username, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
   $params = array($file_name , $path, $username, $type);
   if (sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params) === TRUE) {
       // success 
   } else {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270210/upload-multiple-files-to-server-and?rq=1

Comment: What's the output of ```echo count($_FILES['my_file']['name'])```

Comment: @WalkerBoh The count is 3, i also can print all the file names and paths.

Comment: Don't echo until the files have been processed. Once you echo something back to the client, the server side script ends.

Comment: @WalkerBoh I removed all the echo but still it seems the script ended after the first insert.

Comment: Can you show the code for ```insertFile_info()```?

Comment: @WalkerBoh i added the code below

Comment: @WalkerBoh Hi i have added the insert method. Could you please take a look if you can, Thanks.

Comment: Did you remove the echos from your if else statements in the first block of code?

Comment: @WalkerBoh THANKS! it works now

Comment: Cool. Just so you know, anytime you echo or print something during a client/server call will terminate script execution. Don't echo until you're done with whatever you need to process

Comment: @WalkerBoh That's not true and I don't know where you got that idea. PHP would be pretty useless if you could only ever have a single output statement in a web page.

Comment: @miken32 If you're browsing to a php webpage, then yes you can echo as much as you want. But when a php script is handling an http request, echoing will end the connection.

Comment: @WalkerBoh Are you suggesting PHP can't execute this code? `echo "start"; foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {echo " $k=$v ";} echo " finish";`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem solved itself, but I'll post a suggestion for your code anyway. Preparing a query uses a lot of overhead; if you're going to be executing a query multiple times, you should only prepare it once.

```
// initialize the variables
$params = array($file = "", $target_dir = "", $user = "", $ext = "");
$sql = "INSERT INTO URL (file_name, path, username, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
// prepare the statement, it's now bound to the variables
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);

if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'] && count($_FILES['my_file']['name'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['my_file']['name'] as $i => $file) {
        $target_dir = "upload_test/$file";
        $user = "xxx";
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $file = basename($file);
        // now execute the query with the value in the variables
        if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
            echo "Insert file failure";
            // of course, this is just for testing...
            print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
            die();
        }
        echo "Insert file success";   
    }
}
```